# I can I shape a 3D object in a 2D, and the put the unwrap in a new 3D conformation without any deformations?

Tags: modeling

Hello Blender Community!

I would like to know with this exemple, how to bend a 3D object : the skin of a nose in this exemple (so a 3D form into a 2D form without any lost of informations), exactly like a surgeon would put out the skin of the nose and put it in a 2D shape on a table after removing it from a patient. I try to unwrap the skin of the nose.
! (/Users/pc-doc/Desktop/Capture d’écran 2016-06-12 à 01.09.02.png)

Then I would like to put this unwrap nose, without deformations, on the forehead so in it's 2D form but now with the shape of the forehead. Like that, the surgeon will have a mold to draw a new nose on the forehead.

Comment: A UV bake may do a part of the job. It encodes the 3D shape into the color of the baked image (think about X Y Z encoded in R G B). But I am not skilled enough to answer the question in its totallity. Some informations here : https://sites.google.com/site/amandalevitsky/sculptedprims

Answer (score 1):

The answer is by no means without flaw.

Start by enabling Import-Export UV Layout && Import-Export: Scalable Vector Graphics in add-ons

[image]

In UV editor select desired map + open UVs menu --> Export UV Layout

[image]

Make sure to export as .svg

[image]

Last File --> Import --> svg

[image]

Every polygon is going to be its own curve so Alt + C --> convert to mesh from curve and join them after.

It's not perfect

Comment: you can also mark seams along the face to minimize distortions

Comment: Ok, but when I import it again, the size of the unwrap nose, know change in multiple curve, is extremely small... I lost all the size information of the unwrap nose in fact and it make the computer go very slow because there is to much meshs.

Is there any other solution to make a 3D object going into a 2D form without going through unwrap and svg file? Like that I will have always mesh, and after that I could maybe use shrink-wrap modifier to apply it on the forehead?